# Numpy indexing with argsort

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For 1d indexing array with the result of argsort on that array gives you a sorted array.

```
ar = numpy.random.random(4)
s = numpy.argsort(ar)
ar[s].shape
(4,)
```

But for 3d i am getting:

```
ar = numpy.random.random((2,3,2))
s = numpy.argsort(ar)
ar[s].shape
(2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
```

How can i get same behavior for 3d array as for 1d?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.argsort` sorts a multi-dimensional array along its last axis, unless specified otherwise. Your `s.shape` is the same as `ar.shape`, but the fact that you can even use `ar[s]` without getting IndexErrors is just because you chose a nice shape to begin with.

You first have to think about what you really want to sort. Say you have:

```
[[8, 7],
 [6, 5],
 [4, 3]]
```

What do you want to get? Left to right:

```
[[7, 8],
 [5, 6],
 [3, 4]]
```

or top to bottom:

```
[[4, 3],
 [6, 5],
 [8, 7]]
```

or completely:

```
[[3, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [7, 8]]
```

The last one is probably easiest to flatten and then reshape.

```
arf = ar.flatten()
s = numpy.argsort(arf)
arf[s].reshape(ar.shape)
```

The first one is a bit harder:

```
s = numpy.argsort(ar)
numpy.array([[ar2[s2] for ar2, s2 in zip(ar1, s1)] for ar1, s1 in zip(ar, s)])
```

The last one is homework.